# прошедшая дата с фиксированным временем

Tags: python, datetime

Вот я получил дату и время 4 дня назад ровно. Но незнаю как получить 4 дня назад в 4:00. Можете с этим помочь? Мне нужно чтоб при каждом запуске он 4ехдневней давности дату брал и 4ч утра

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `.replace(hour=4, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)`

Comment: @andreymal может сделаете как ответ?

Comment: @Стас мне лень.

Comment: Приведите код в текстовом виде, а не картинкой

Answer (score 0):

```
dayStart = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 4)
dayStart = dayStart.replace(hour=4, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```